# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol - msvc debug build for function template

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am getting error LNK2019 only during MSVC debug build for following type of code structure for function 'doSomething'. The code compiles fine for optimized build. Can somebody please help?

//header file - abc.h

```
class __declspec(dllimport) Test /* some functions of class Test are defined in DLL - abc */ {
   // members
   public: 
   template <typename T>
   _forceinline int doSomething(T var)
   { 
      //do some thing
      return var.size(); 
   }
}
```

//cpp file

```
 /*part of another DLL which does not link to DLL 'abc' */
    #include "abc.h"
    int main() {
        Test t; 
        Test1 var1; 
        t.doSomething( var1 );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely the debug build will not inline the function. Despite its name, `_forceinline` is still just a request to the compiler, and the default debug setting is to not inline anything.

So, if the `doSomething` function isn't used elsewhere in the DLL, it will not be instantiated anywhere, and the linker cannot find it.

Comment: will the removal of  forceinline help in this case? The function doSomething() will get defined in 2 DLLs, but if they do not link with each other, will it be fine to do it?

Comment: This might indeed be the case, but in my experience, `__forceinline` *does* get applied in debug builds. And while it is simply a request, I rarely see the compiler ignore it. The only times I've ever seen it not inline a function marked `__forceinline` is when it legitimately *cannot* inline it. It will inline functions that are pages and pages of code, when inlining is actually a really stupid thing to do.